# I am using a webview in Android for my web application which is responsive

Tags: android-webview

I am creating an android app using webview, The login is also done via my web pages. Now evertime the user opens up the app, he is directed to the Login screen, even if he has logged in previously. Is there any way to store that session and use it when the user uses the app next time?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Comment: You should include some explanation of your answer - How and why does what you propose answer the question.